# Laravel - Grouping eloquent query by date and user

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I have the following database table 'observations'
[image]

I am trying to make table by group the observations using three criteria (date - user_id - Type_Name_ID):-

[image]

There is no way coming into my mind of how to form an laravel query to get the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can start from the known SQL query statement to get these results and use the [methods provided in Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html).

```
>>> $observationsQuery = DB::table('observations')
  ->selectRaw('date, count(observation_id), user_id, Type_Name_ID')
  ->groupBy('date', 'user_id', 'Type_Name_ID');

>>> $observationsQuery->toSql();

=> "select date, count(observation_id), user_id, Type_Name_ID from "observations" 
   group by "date", "user_id", "Type_Name_ID""
```